# The thesis reference style is not complete

Tags: bibliographies, thesis

I use "ieeetran" and the following code to generate the reference (without URL information)

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEfull,paper01Const}
```

however, the result is 
"Y. Qian, “Design and Control of a Personal Assistant Robot,” Ph.D.
dissertation."

And the generated .bib files is

```
@phdthesis{qian_design_2013,
  location = {{France}},
  title = {Design and {{Control}} of a {{Personal Assistant Robot}}},
  url = {https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00864692/document},
  abstract = {The purpose of this thesis is to design, model and control of a personal assistant robot used for domestic tasks. In order to make the robot's design more efficient, a virtual simulation system is built using dynamic simulation software. ...},
  pagetotal = {214},
  timestamp = {2017-07-06T15:44:04Z},
  langid = {english},
  institution = {{Ecole Centrale de Lille}},
  author = {Qian, Yang},
  urldate = {2016-02-25},
  date = {2013-07-04},
  file = {Full Text PDF:C\:\\Users\\Yan WEI\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zotero\\Zotero\\Profiles\\jf7ifsnc.default\\zotero\\storage\\35UHZBC4\\Qian - 2013 - Design and Control of a Personal Assistant Robot.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

Wherever, the complete reference is

"Yang Qian. Design and Control of a Personal Assistant Robot. Other. Ecole Centrale de Lille,
2013. English."

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You could edit your question. Please dont ask the same question twice. Your code is still no MWE(B). The code should be compilable.

Comment: Unrelated: `Ecole Centrale de Lille` should be `École Centrale de Lille`.

Comment: Isnt it normal for IEEE to use the initial of the given name?

Comment: I mean that there is no "year" information, neither the school information. Thank you very much.

Comment: IEEEtran is an old style for the BibTeX system. Your database entry is suitable for the modern [biblatex system](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber) (<- Link). IEEEtran does not know `date` or `landid`. `timestamp` is added by your management software and is completely useless to both LaTeX bib systems.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 3):

The shown bib entry is to be used with the modern package `biblatex`. With classic BibTeX and the `IEEEtran` style, you get the following output because the style does not know all those field types.

[image: yanIeeeBib]

[image: yanIeeeBiblatex]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{qian_design_2013,
  location = {{France}},
  title = {Design and {{Control}} of a {{Personal Assistant Robot}}},
  url = {https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00864692/document},
  abstract = {The purpose of this thesis is to design, model and control of a personal assistant robot used for domestic tasks. In order to make the robot's design more efficient, a virtual simulation system is built using dynamic simulation software. ...},
  pagetotal = {214},
  timestamp = {2017-07-06T15:44:04Z},
  langid = {english},
  institution = {{École Centrale de Lille}},
  author = {Qian, Yang},
  urldate = {2016-02-25},
  date = {2013-07-04},
  file = {Full Text PDF:C\:\\Users\\Yan WEI\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zotero\\Zotero\\Profiles\\jf7ifsnc.default\\zotero\\storage\\35UHZBC4\\Qian - 2013 - Design and Control of a Personal Assistant Robot.pdf:application/pdf}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Reference with biblatex]
\end{document}
```

A better entry for the class system would produce the following. Please note that the note is output *before* the url, which is printed last for `IEEEtran.bst`

[image: yanIeeeBibMod]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{qian_design_2013,
  author = {Qian, Yang},
  title = {Design and {{Control}} of a {{Personal Assistant Robot}}},
  url = {https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00864692/document},
  pagetotal = {214},
  timestamp = {2017-07-06T15:44:04Z},
  langid = {english},
  school = {{École Centrale de Lille, France}},
  note = {(visited on 02/25/2016)},
year={2013},
month={Jul.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\end{document}
```